# Java and MySql. Which exception really need "rollback"

Tags: java, mysql

I am starting use Java to operate MySql database. I learned that rollback may be required when some exception happens. But I am wondering which instructions exception really needs it.

My operating sequence is like this:

1. `getConnection();`
2. `setAutoCommit(false);`
3. `createStatement();`
4. `addBatch(str1);`
5. `addBatch(str2);`
6. `addBatch(str3);`
7. `executeBatch();`
8. `commit();`
9. `statement.close();`
10. `connection.close();`

Each step may generate an exception. 
Which step's exception that I should do a rollback for?

I did some trials and now I think the key step is "commit". Before it, nothing is affected so rollback is unnecessary. After it, rollback is useless. So, is it good enough to do rollback just in commit's exception?

Comment: If you are trying to execute one or more statements in a transaction and get a SQLException, call the method rollback to end the transaction and start the transaction all over again

Comment: Thanks for notyou comment. But I don't really know what "MySql transcation" is in Java coding. In my steps, I cannot see what is about "transaction".

Comment: Or you are saying that I need to do rollback for "executeBatch" exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, exception may occur at any time those exception handle it properly.

Executing the batch of SQL query's will be start at 7th step which is executeBatch(); Here if you get any exception before commit(8th step) the data to database tables you should do rollback, so the original data wont be modified if you skip the commit.

Comment: Thanks. Allow me to double confirm your suggestion. I should do rollback in executeBatch() exception handling, instead of in commit()'s. Right?

Comment: Yes, While execution time any exception comes, then there only you do rollback.